# JavaScript on third party website

Tags: javascript

I am working on building a Chrome extension that injects bits and pieces of JavaScript onto websites, a bit like AdBlock does.

What is the best way to develop/test my JavaScript code on third-party websites? I want to have my custom JavaScript loaded as if it was JavaScript from the original website.

Comment: Sounds questionable, why don't you tell us more about this.

Comment: I would like to add custom JavaScript on Wikipedia, as an extension. It would be a little tool/add-on to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Chrome's developer console. Right click, go to inspect element, and go to console. Alternatively, press ctrl+shift+j.

You should write the code in notepad++ or a similar text editor and then copy it into the console and run it to test it.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But is there a way to automate the process?

Comment: This should help: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

It's a tutorial from Google on making extensions.